# nodejs xmlHttpRequest similar

Tags: cookies, node.js, xmlhttprequest

What is the similar of xmlHttpRequest in node.js?

I want to request a site and get its setted cookies and make a new request using those cookies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the similar of xmlHttpRequest in node.js?

Try to look at [http.request](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.10/api/http.html#http.request) method in docs.

> I want to request a site and get its setted cookies and make a new
>   request using those cookies.

There are some node.js modules which deal with cookies, for example [cookies](https://github.com/jed/cookies).

Answer (score 0):

There are also `request` and `xmlhttprequest` NPM libraries. Built-in http.request is too low-level.